# load Matlab's GeneralizedLinearModel in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have once created and trained a GeneralizedLinearModel in Matlab, then saved it to my drive. Regularly I load this model in Matlab and use the '.predict' on some data. Now I would like to load the saved model (with its specific coefficients) into Python and run the'.predic' the same as in Matlab.
Does anyone know how to do that or alternatively how to implement the prediction given the coefficients?

Comment: If you have MATLAB installed in the PC, the easiest way is probably running MATLAB from python whenever you need it. "How to implement a GLM"? With great effort and time from your side.

Comment: Calling Matlab is not an option

Comment: Then the other options are too complicated for a question in SO, I believe. A `GeneralizedLinearModel` is a matlab class, so you cannot "just load it", thus you need to implement not a GLM, but a GLM exactly the same as MATLAB implements it... Easier to find GLM code for python and retrain it. You could alternatively create some matlab executable from your code